# Delete and re-create Cosmos DB containers with different partition key ... Creates with same partition key

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a notebook in Cosmos DB and I am trying to delete and create several containers.

We have various environments and no access to Live, so I need this script to do all the work.

I have the following containers (and partition keys)

ContA(part1)

ContB(part2)

ContC(part3)

I know I can't change the partition keys, so I want to delete the containers and create the following with a new partition key

ContA(part4)

ContB(part4)

ContC(part4)

I am using the following code to do this

```
from azure.cosmos.partition_key import PartitionKey

# Create new database
database = cosmos_client.get_database_client("MyCosmosDB")

# FIRST SCRIPT
# Get a list of all current containers and if there are any, 
# iterate through and delete them all
containers = list(database.list_containers())
if containers:
    for container in containers:        
        print("Deleting the " + container['id'] + " container...")
        try:                   
            database.delete_container(container['id'])           
        except errors.CosmosHttpResponseError as e:
            raise
else:
    print("Ther are no containers in container to delete in this database")

# SECOND SCRIPT
# Create containers
ContAContainer = database.create_container(id='ContA', partition_key=PartitionKey(path='/part4'))
print("Creating ContA container...\n")
ContBContainer = database.create_container(id='ContB', partition_key=PartitionKey(path='/part4'))
print("Creating ContB container...\n")
ContCContainer = database.create_container(id='ContC', partition_key=PartitionKey(path='/part4'))
print("Creating ContC container...\n")
```

**Problem:**
If I run the # FIRST SCRIPT and # SECOND SCRIPT separately, everything is fine.
If I run the first part of this script (the deletes) this deletes the containers fine.

If I run the second part of this script (the creates) this creates them fine, with the part4 partition keys.

but with the old containers in place, When I run them together like above, the containers keep their original partition keys... so ContA still has part1 as it's partition key, not part4 as defined in the # SECOND SCRIPT.

Can anyone advise what is going on here and how I can create the containers with the correct partition keys from this one script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code.

> but with the old containers in place, When I run them together like
> above, the containers keep their original partition keys... so ContA
> still has part1 as it's partition key, not part4 as defined in the #
> SECOND SCRIPT.

This seems to be a display bug. After I execute notebook, I click `Refresh tree` button, it still shows original partition keys("/part1","/part2","/part3") as you described. But when I refresh my page of browser, partition key will be "/part4".

Comment: Thank you Steve ... it is something I should have tried to be fair... I was fooled by the refresh button!! Thanks again :)